# Angular js sorting with comparator function

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I need to sort my products by title - it works without any problem with `orderBy:'+title'` inside my ng-repeat, but some of my products title contains numbers and I would like to move these products with numbers to the end.

I think I need to use this syntax now:

```
 <div ng-repeat="product in products | filter : search | orderBy: '+title:false:localeSensitiveComparator' ">
```

and add the comparator function, but have no idea how to do it (what condition should I use inside the function):

```
            $scope.localeSensitiveComparator = function(v1, v2) {

          what condtion should I use here to detect and compare digits in the title?


          // Compare numbers alphabetically, taking locale into account
          return v1.value.localeCompare(v2.value);
        };
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

I have this order now (with only orderBy: '+title')
https://prnt.sc/lk4no1

I would like this:
https://prnt.sc/lk4q2c

Comment: Show us example of your input and desired output

Comment: I've added example screenshots.